# Bootstrap - Center img in row vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying forever to center this image properly in the row containing the div the img is in. Here's my html

```
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3 style="text-transform: uppercase"><strong>Title</strong></h3>
                    <p>Text</p>
                    <br>
                    <h3 style="text-transform: uppercase"><strong>Title</strong></h3>
                    <p>Text</p>
                    <br>
                    <h3 style="text-transform: uppercase"><strong>Title</strong></h3>
                    <p>Text(2 male, 1 female, 3 mixed characters)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img class="img-full center-block" src="img/img.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

I've tried all the suggestions on this page and none of them seem to work. https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

I do not know the height of the element since this is a responsive website, so I tried using translate to move the image, and this happened.

[image]

If I use flexbox, then my mobile design breaks because the columns don't collapse right, like this.

[image]

If I use this code

```
.vcenter {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
float: none;
}
```

Nothing happens

[image]

So I feel like I've exhausted any well known solutions. Anyone have any idea how to fix this? I have a feeling my issue is linked to my stacking columns within columns, but if I don't do that it breaks my design too...

Edit: This is how I want it to look

[image]

Comment: I'm confused as to how you are wanting it to look. Can you sketch out a layout or describe it a little more? You've shown a lot of ways you *don't* want it to look, but how do you want it to look?

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to vertically center the image. Is that correct?

Comment: It would also help to create a JSFiddle or Stack Snippet that illustrates the issue.

Comment: Give an image `margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point you won't be able to vertically align the image because the containing col-md-2 will shrink down to the height of the image.  You'll need to ensure that the parent element of the image has larger height value. You can set it to the height of the col-md-9 statically in your css (like I have done in the snippet) or have it check dynamically by javascript. Then you can run the code I have below (the css will work IE 9 and up, I also changed bootstrap class to xs to illustrate in the snippet):

```css
.vcenter {
position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.taller{ height:300px;
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-9">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h3 style="text-transform: uppercase"><strong>Title</strong></h3>
                    <p>Text</p>
                    <br>
                    <h3 style="text-transform: uppercase"><strong>Title</strong></h3>
                    <p>Text</p>
                    <br>
                    <h3 style="text-transform: uppercase"><strong>Title</strong></h3>
                    <p>Text(2 male, 1 female, 3 mixed characters)</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 taller">
                <img class="img-full center-block vcenter" src="img/img.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**This should do it for the JAVASCRIPT version**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   matchColHeight();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    matchColHeight();
}); 

function matchColHeight() {
  var col1_height = $('.col1').height(); 
  $('.col2').css('height', col1_height);  
}
```

```css
.vcenter {
    position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col1">
                        <h3 style="text-transform: uppercase"><strong>Title</strong></h3>
                        <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
                        <br>
                        <h3 style="text-transform: uppercase"><strong>Title</strong></h3>
                        <p>Text</p>
                        <br>
                        <h3 style="text-transform: uppercase"><strong>Title</strong></h3>
                        <p>Text(2 male, 1 female, 3 mixed characters)</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 col2">
                    <img class="img-full center-block vcenter" src="img/img.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was working on an answer of my own, but I couldn't get the CSS top attribute to work... can you figure out why? http://jsfiddle.net/sseoLwda/

Comment: did you have position set to "relative"?

Comment: Yes, I had an <img> next to the text div all within a wrapper div.

Comment: Ok, so I've got this in my codepen http://codepen.io/Kathrynwatts/pen/vNyNgZ. How could I find the height dynamically? I want to avoid setting a height statically.

Comment: @Seeshi_suin I have added a snippet with javascript to find the height of the first column. I'm using jquery.

Comment: @tnschmidt, you're a lifesaver :)

Comment: @amklose, if you inspect the wrapper div in your example, you will see it has no height. You'll need to ensure it has a height (possibly a clearfix edit), then work from there.

Comment: @Seeshi_suin, that js shouldnt slow much down.